# HTML5 <input type="number" ... being able to show number as well as well as alphabets as choices

Tags: html, input, numbers, words

I have the following HTML5 tag which is working fine but I want extra functionality in it.

`<input class="form-field-short" type="number" min="1" max="5" value="0" name="someName" />`

I get an input field with choices between 1 and 12.

Now I want it to allow strings along with the current choices.

`For example..  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ABC, DEF, GHI, XYZ`

Elsewhere, in my code, I have also used `<select><option></option></select>` but that is not what I want. 
I am looking for `<input type="number" ....>` tag with the capability of showing numbers as well as words in the choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is a numeric text input that also lists some non-numeric options (usually shown in a pulldown menu by the browser):

```
<input type="text" list="list" inputmode="numeric"/>
<datalist id="list">
    <option value="ABC"/>
    <option value="DEF"/>
    <option value="GHI"/>
</datalist>
```

However, if the overall set of options, including numbers, is limited, then a `<select>` might be more appropriate, and is more widely supported:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="GHI">GHI</option>
</select>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Br5S4/1/).

Comment: your answer is a good alternative and I temporarily implemented the `<select><option></option></select>`. But that still does not answer my question.

Comment: The buttons you see when you click in a number field on a touchscreen platform are generated by the browser, not the page. So if you want to change how they behave, the only option is to implement your own set of buttons in html.

Comment: I get it now. I will do as you suggestions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to provide choices for visitors, you should probably use a drop down menu like this:

```
   <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="AABB">AABB</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="XRZ">XRZ</option>
   </select>
```